# Swift function forward-declaration or prototype

Tags: swift, compilation

In Objective-C (or C in general), if I'm going to have two files like

**main.m:**

```m
void foo();

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.m:**

```m
void foo() {
    // do something
}
```

I can compile main.m to main.o without even having foo.m, then compile foo.m and link with main.o:

```sh
$ clang -c main.m

# later
$ clang main.o foo.m -o FooExecutable
```

My understanding is that the forward-declaration or prototype on the first line of main.m is what makes this work.

Is there a way to create the same kind of setup in Swift?  I haven't found a way to make a corresponding main.swift compile.

**main.swift:**

```
// How do I tell the compiler to trust me that foo() will be implemented?

foo()
```

**foo.swift:**

```
func foo() {
    // do something
}
```

And then:

```sh
# This works:
$ swiftc main.swift foo.swift -o FooExecutable

# This doesn't:
$ swiftc -emit-object main.swift

main.swift:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'foo'
foo()
^~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare a function in Swift without defining it, the compiler
needs "foo.swift" in order to compile "main.swift".

Here is an example how one can compile Swift files separately and then link the object files:

```
swift -frontend -c -module-name myprog -primary-file main.swift foo.swift
swift -frontend -c -module-name myprog -primary-file foo.swift main.swift

swiftc -o myprog main.o foo.o
```

This is a very simple example, for real applications you probably need to import
additional frameworks and set more options. It can be instructive to check waht
Xcode does when building a project, the full compiler and linker output
can be found in the Report navigator.

See also [SWIFT MAKEFILES – TAKE 2](https://owensd.io/2015/01/15/swift-makefiles-take-2/)
for a general GNU Make based solution.

Another option is to compile against a 
.swiftmodule and a shared library, compare e.g. [How do I import a swift function declared in a compiled .swiftmodule into another swift file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296470/how-do-i-import-a-swift-function-declared-in-a-compiled-swiftmodule-into-anothe).
Then `func foo` must be marked as `public`:

**foo.swift:**

```
public func foo() {
    print("foo")
}
```

```
swiftc -emit-module -emit-library -module-name Foo -module-link-name Foo foo.swift
```

creates Foo.swiftmodule and libFoo.dylib (this can also be done in
separate steps). Now main.swift can import the Foo module

**main.swift:**

```
import Foo
foo()
```

```
swiftc -emit-object -I . main.swift
```

and the object file can be linked against the shared library:

```
swiftc -o myprog -L . main.o
```

Comment: From the linked answer, it sounds like the .swiftmodule file describes the interface, but doesn't contain the implementation, so I can do something like `swiftc -emit-module foo.swift -module-name FooModule -module-link-name FooModule` with an empty implementation of `foo()` and `swiftc -emit-object -I . main.swift` to compile main.swift into main.o; then, once foo.swift is implemented, `swiftc -emit-library foo.swift -module-name FooModule -module-link-name FooModule` to build the library and `swiftc main.o -L .` to build/link the final executable.  I think this is actually working, too...

Comment: @Isaac: Yes, that's what I meant with the "another option". Only the .swiftmodule is needed for compiling, but the .dylib for linking. – But then you have a main executable "main" which *depends on* the shared library "libFooModule.dylib", whereas in the other solution (and in your C example) you have  a main executable only.

Comment: Ahh, I'd overlooked that the library was dynamic.  I think that still works for my purposes.  Would you mind if I edited the details of the process into your answer?  (I'd rather have those details in your answer and accept that than add those details in a separate answer.)