# {Module_name}-Swift.h file not working well only in Swift 4 projects unlike Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, migration

Anyone faced problems in `{Module_name}-Swift.h` file for `Swift 4` projects? I've noticed `-Swift.h` autogenerated file not working well with `Swift 4` syntax unlike `Swift 3.2`!.

For example, `-Swift.h` file doesn't contain all variables and methods which implemented in the custom Swift classes which inherited from `NSObject` class!

I've used `@objc` and `@class`keywords but no way.

- I don't get any errors! the problem is if I've created a class like this:

> ```
> import Foundation
> class Utils: NSObject {
>     let abc: String?
>     func xyz() { 
>         print("")
>     }
> }
> ```

and navigate to `{Module_name}-Swift.h` I see something like that:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC3{Module_name}5Utils") 
@interface Utils : NSObject 
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER; 
@end
```

**Problem**

Both `let abc: String?` and `func xyz()` have been never included in `{Modue_name}-Swift.h`file!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762460/swift-4-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4

Comment: @elgawady14 As to why it's not working with your project, can you edit your answer with the error?

Comment: @OliverAtkinson thanks for the reply, checkout my last update.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Swift 4 you have to mark a lot more things `@objc` (nothing implicit anymore) but other than that it should just be in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can all check it to confirm class name in .h file like:

@class filename;

Answer (score 0):

The generated file `{Module}-Swift.h` does not contain your variables and methods, the file is generated to give you access to the Module namespace.

The actual interface for the generated module lives in `Module.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule` (depending on built architecture).

More information on its contents:

- https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2502
- https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160111/000827.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396175/1755720

however... the format is not documented anywhere and is subject to change. A good starting point would be to look in `include/swift/Serialization/ModuleFormat.h`

---

As to why it's not working - Swift 4 has a migration process, please ensure you have followed it: https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4/

Xcode will pick up *most* things ... but it won't get everything!

Comment: I've mentioned the problem specifically for the case I've faced in my last update.

Comment: @elgawady14 And how are you getting access to the `-Swift.h` file? Typically the generated one won't have any header information like the one you are posting - I'm happy to take a look if you can produce it in a simple sample project

Comment: sry for late reply! you can access `-Swift.h` file after you build your code by highlighting `{your_module}-Swift.h` and right click then go to 'Jump to Definition', the file content will shown up immediately!

Answer (score -1):

And why do you need header files for Swift classes? You just can mark swift class as @objc and you will be able to reach all its properties.

Comment: It does, because it would fix his problem. Mark swift class with @objc and you won't even need header files.